# How do I draw multiple images onto the canvas at once?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Right now the code is as follows:

```
const one = new Image(); 
one.src = "img/one.png";
const two = new Image();
two.src = "img/two.png";

function imgs(ctx) {
    one.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(one, 50, 50);
    };
    two.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(two, 100, 100);
    };
}
```

Can I wait for 'all' of the images to be loaded first, and than draw them all at the same time on the canvas? Currently it'll draw an image once it's been loaded, and than another once that is loaded, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create an image loader `Promise`, and then pass all three to `Promise.all` to await their `load` calls.

The use of `Promise` and `async`/`await` is preferred over a separate counter variable.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('#draw').getContext('2d');

const loadImage = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
  img.addEventListener('error', (err) => reject(err));
  img.src = url;
});

const imageUrls = [
  'https://via.placeholder.com/100/FF7777/FFFFFF?text=A',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/100/77FF77/FFFFFF?text=B',
  'https://via.placeholder.com/100/7777FF/FFFFFF?text=C'
];

Promise
  .all(imageUrls.map(loadImage))
  .then(([one, two, three]) => {
    console.log('Drawing all three images...');
    ctx.drawImage(one, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(two, 100, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(three, 200, 0);
  });
```

```html
<canvas id="draw" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
```

---

### Beginner help

#### Selectors

The [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method is preferred over the [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) because it it easier to work with and supports attribute selectors.

This: `document.querySelector('#draw')` is preferred over `document.getElementById('draw')` or `window.draw`.

**Note:** There is also a multi-element selector function called [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

#### Iterators

The [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method returns a new array (iterates through the array) with a new value for each value visited. In the example above, each string is transformed into a `Promise`. The same code can be written more verbosely:

```js
Promise.all(imageUrls.map(function(imageUrl) {
  return loadImage(imageUrl); // returns a Promise<Image>
}));
```

Comment: On a side note; what's the difference between 'document.querySelector()' and 'document.getElementById()'? Am also checking what 'map' does. But this seems like a good solution.

Comment: @23rfew I edited the question and included some explanation at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep a counter of the number of images loaded, and wait to act until all are loaded:

```
const one = new Image(); 
one.src = "img/one.png";
const two = new Image();
two.src = "img/two.png";

let numToLoad = 2;
let numLoaded = 0;

function imgs(ctx) {
    function incLoaded() {
        numLoaded++;
        if(numLoaded == numToLoad){
            ctx.drawImage(one, 50, 50);
            ctx.drawImage(two, 100, 100);
        }
    }
    one.onload = incLoaded;
    two.onload = incLoaded;
}
```